# PIG Item Count and Histogram

Tags: apache-pig, histogram, frequency

This is a two part problem:

PART 1:

I am using the cloudera pig editor to transform my data.  The data set is derived from the US Patents Citations data set.  The first column is the "Cited" patent. The remaining data is the patents that cite the first patent.

3858241 3634889,3557384,3398406,1324234,956203

3858242 3707004,3668705,3319261,1515701

3858243 3684611,3681785,3574238,3221341,3156927,3146465,2949611

3858244 2912700,2838924,2635670,2211676,17445,14040

3858245 3755824,3699969,3621837,3608095,3553737,3176316,2072303

3858246 3601877,3503079,3451067

3858247 3755824,3694819,3621837,2807431,1600859

I need to create PIG code that will count the number of citation that the first patent has.  So, I need the output to be:

3858241 5

3858242 4

3858243 7

3858244 6

3858245 7

3858246 3

3858247 6

PART 2:
I need to create a histogram of the output from problem 1 using a PIG script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this script should work.

```
X = LOAD 'pigpatient.txt' using PigStorage(' ') AS (pid:int,str:chararray);

X1 = FOREACH X GENERATE pid,STRSPLIT(str, ',') AS (y:tuple());

X2 = FOREACH X1 GENERATE  pid,SIZE(y) as numofcitan;

dump X2;

X3 = group X2 by numofcitan;

Histograms = foreach X3 GENERATE group as numofcitan,COUNT(X2.pid); 

dump Histograms;
```

input:

3858241 3634889,3557384,3398406,1324234,956203
      3858242 3707004,3668705,3319261,1515701
3858243 3684611,3681785,3574238,3221341,3156927,3146465,2949611
3858244 2912700,2838924,2635670,2211676,17445,14040
3858245 3755824,3699969,3621837,3608095,3553737,3176316,2072303
3858246 3601877,3503079,3451067
3858247 3755824,3694819,3621837,2807431,1600859

Result:

```
  (3858241,5)
  (3858242,4)
  (3858243,7)
  (3858244,6)
  (3858245,7)
  (3858246,3)
  (3858247,5)
```

Histogram output:

```
 Number of citatatins,number of patients

(3,1)
(4,1)
(5,2)
(6,1)
(7,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Sravan K Reddy's answer is good enough to be a solution, but it is essential to know what is histogram?

Histogram is frequency distribution of datasets and gives statistical information about data. Most commonly used histogram types are; Equi-width and equi-depth which is called equi-height or height-balanced.

In database tools, equi-depth histogram is prefered. ex: Oracle [see](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_histo.htm#TGSQL379)

@Sravan K Reddy intends to create equi-width histogram of patent citations. However, in order to create histogram, data must be sorted. That is vital for histogram construction.

If you want to create histogram of your big data, read [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.05633.pdf) and check [Apache Pig Scripts](https://github.com/tolgabuyuktanir/Equi-DepthHistogramConstroctionDemonstrations).